# Is there a way to check the DB2 sql log for actual SQL operations executed into it?, ie how many rows were fetched etc?

Tags: database, db2

I am using a DB2 v10.5, and I am pushing messages into the database I created using a gateway. Is there a way to check the DB2 sql logs for actual SQL operation executed?, ie how many rows were fetched etc? While googling, I find these logs inside the DB2 server in the DIAGPATH `/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/` but I don't see any SQL messages in there.

I have been checking DB2 guides as well but any ideas to help me on this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by logs? Each statement returns the number of rows as part of the metadata. Where do you need that data? There is also monitoring functionality in Db2.

Comment: @data_henrik thank you for reply. By logs I mean any transaction logs in the DB2 server that may contain details about the SQL transactions. I needed these logs to verify something on the changes we made in the gateway side (I use to pump messages into the db). When you said "Each statement returns the number of rows as part of the metadata", which file are these data found? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Activity event monitoring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/c0055565.html)

Briefly:
It acts like "logger" for executed statements. The information is written to the tables of such an event monitor for sessions with such a "logging" enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the package cache. This holds aggregate metrics for all executions of a statement that are still in the package cache (entries get evicted from the cache as newer statement arrive). [MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055017.html)

You can also use the [Db2 Database Management Console](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/db2-data-management-console) which is

> A new browser-based console that helps you administer, monitor, manage and optimize the performance of IBM Db2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows databases.

and which itself collects data via functions such as MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT and Activity Event Monitors